# A-Frame | How to detect right controller in order to set right event?

Tags: javascript, events, controller, aframe, virtual-reality

I'm making a vr app using `aframevr` and I'd like that it works with all controller compatibles.

Here is my try which doesn't work on when I tested with a smartphone and Daydream bundle.

**JavaScript :**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('controller', {
      dependencies: ['tracked-controls'],

      schema: {
           hand: { default: 'right' }
      },

      init: function () {
           let  config = this.config,
                data = this.data,
                self = this.el;

           // track all types of controllers
           self.setAttribute('daydream-controls', { hand: data.hand, model: false });
           self.setAttribute('gearvr-controls', { hand: data.hand, model: false });
           self.setAttribute('oculus-touch-controls', { hand: data.hand, model: false });
           self.setAttribute('vive-controls', { hand: data.hand, model: false });

           // wait for controller to connect
           self.addEventListener('controllerconnected', event => {
                let controllerConfig = config[event.detail.name];

                self.addEventListener(controllerConfig.triggerEvent, () => {
                     handleTrigger('0');
                });
           });
      },

      config: {
           'daydream-controls': {
                triggerEvent: 'trackpadup'
           },
           'gearvr-controls': {
                triggerEvent: 'trackpadup'
           },
           'oculus-touch-controls': {
                triggerEvent: 'triggerup'
           },
           'vive-controls': {
                triggerEvent: 'triggerup'
           }
      }
 });
```

**HTML :**

```
<a-entity controller></a-entity>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What smartphone? Daydream is only supported on Pixel 1/2/3 phones and has been discontinued for Pixel 4 and any other future phones. I recommend using desktop VR or standalone headsets like Oculus Go / Quest that are fully supported.

Comment: asus zenphone AR

Comment: No idea what the daydream sun setting timeline is. I wouldn't be surprised if it stopped working in latest Chrome versions.You can try verify with the following example: https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/ I recommend reconsidering Daydream compatibility since the platform has been discontinued by Google.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time.